# Error in row Mysql html/php

Tags: php, html, mysql, row

```
    <?PHP
    $select = 'SELECT cliente, pedido, data, valor from financial';
    $result = mysql_query($select);
    $medium = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            printf('
                <form name="frmFinanceiro" id="frmFinanceiro" action="frmFinanceiro" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="six columns">
                            <br><br><br>
                            <input type="text" name="cliente" placeholder="Cliente" value="%s" style="background:#F0E68C; color:black;"/>
                            <input type="text" name="pedido" placeholder="Pedido" value="%s" style="background:#F0E68C; color:black;"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="six columns">
                            <br><br><br>
                            <input type="text" name="data" value="%s" placeholder="Data" style="background:#F0E68C; color:black;"/>
                            <input type="text" name="Valor" value="%s" placeholder="Valor" style="background:#F0E68C; color:black;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <input type="submit" value="Alterar" class="button success" />
                    </center>
                </form>
            ', $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3]);
        }

    ?>
```

I have this code, why is it jumping the first result?
It is only showing id > 1 of my DB :(
I rewrited it 3x+ and no success.

Comment: Remove the `$medium = mysql_fetch_row($result);`, essentially you are reading one row from the stream with `mysql_fetch_row` that you do not use, then in the `while` loop you read the second one and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$medium = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

fetches a row. Since you never use `$medium` anywhere, you're basically throwing away that row.

Answer (score 0):

It's jumping the first result because you retrieve the first result *before* the while loop, and throw it away:

```
$result = mysql_query($select); 
$medium = mysql_fetch_row($result);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array(....)) {
```

mysql_fetch_row does roughly the same thing as mysql_fetch_array. Get rid of that function call and your mysql_fetch_array will start from the first row.

On a sidenote: you really should not use the mysql extension anymore, but rather either [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).